# Stripslashes() not working in email

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm trying to make an email notification whenever somebody submits a comment going into a database. I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to protect against injections and I'm trying to strip the slashses off the name, email, and comment when they are sent in the email notification. The database entry code is commented out, as I don't want there to be an entry made every time I test the email system.

The email is sent just fine, however `stripslashes()` is not working properly. For example, if the message is "Can't wait!" the email will have "Comment: Can\'t wait!". This is strange to me because when I have the comments displayed on the page, stripslashses works fine.

Is this because I'm not applying `stripslashes()` to data not coming directly out of the database?

```
$li = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db($dbDatabase, $li) or die ("could not select DB"); 

    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($HTTP_POST_VARS["name"]);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($HTTP_POST_VARS["email"]);
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($HTTP_POST_VARS["comment"]);
    $date = Date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    /*
    $gb_query =     "insert into entries
            values(0, '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$date')";

    mysql_query($gb_query);
    $res = mysql_affected_rows();

    // See if insert was successful or not
    if($res > 0) {

    $ret_str="Your guestbook entry was successfully added!";*/
        $name2=stripslashes($name);
        $email2=stripslashes($email);
        $comment2=stipslashes($comment);
        $subject = 'New Guestbook Entry Has been Added!';
        $message = "Name:  $name2\nEmail:  $email2\nComment:  $comment2";
        $to = "chetg329@yahoo.com";
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
        //header('Location: guestbook.php?ps=1');
    //exit(); // End the request
    /*  
    } else {
        $ret_str = "There was a problem with your guestbook entry. Please try again.";
    }

    // Append success/failure message
    $gb_str .= "<span class=\"ret\">$ret_str</span><BR>";*/
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I completely forgot to add it.

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/04/15-top-php-coding-tutorials-tips-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the problem lies within [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes). I would take a look at your php.ini and see if you can turn it off (pending you are not relying on it to prevent SQL Injection). If you cannot access the php.ini to turn it off PHP provides a method for you to test it and act accordingly (IE stripslashes on the data before escaping it with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) ) It is called [`get_magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

Alternatively, why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` on data that is not being inserted into the database? If you do insert it later on, then move those calls till after the `mail` call.

Comment: It's being added to the database right after the variables are initiated. I just have it commented out because I don't want new entries to be added every time I test the email system. Also, I put the mail call after the database entry because I want to make sure the data was actually entered in the database before emailing the notification.

Comment: If you want to do that, then use the `$_POST` for the `mail` variables instead of the variables that are being escaped.